# Using Polymer.dart to manipulate the shadow DOM from inside a dynamically added custom element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer, web-component

This minimal polymer app has a 'browser' that holds 'tracks'. The browser needs to be able to call `render` on its tracks. When a track renders, it adds a new `<p>` node to its shadow DOM.

As it stands, `render` is called, the ParagraphElement is created and the parent "div#insert-here" is found without any trouble, but adding the newly created ParagraphElement to the div's children doesn't render in the browser.

If we change the code to insert a new `<p>` into the *ExampleBrowser's* shadow dom during enteredView, the `<p>` appears in the browser as expected. Why would it work for the top-level custom element, but not the dynamically created custom element?

**bugTest.dart**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('example-browser')
class ExampleBrowser extends PolymerElement {
    @published ExampleTrack track;

    ExampleBrowser.created() : super.created();

    @override
    void enteredView() {
      track = new Element.tag('example-track')
      ..trackName = "Test Track";
    }

    void renderTrack(MouseEvent e) {
      track.render();
    }
}

@CustomTag('example-track')
class ExampleTrack extends PolymerElement {
    @published String trackName;

    ExampleTrack.created() : super.created();

    void render() {
      ParagraphElement testParagraph = new ParagraphElement()
      ..text = "I don't seem to get added to the DOM :(";
      $['insert-here'].children.add(testParagraph);
    }
  }
```

**custom-elements.html**

```dart
<script type="application/dart" src="bugTest.dart"></script>

<polymer-element name="example-browser">
  <template>
    <h2>Browser</h2>
    <button on-click="{{renderTrack}}">Render tracks</button>
    <example-track trackName={{track.trackName}}></example-track>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="example-track">
  <template>
    <h3>{{trackName}}</h3>
    <div id="insert-here"></div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**index.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BugTest</title>
    <link rel="import" href="custom-elements.html">
    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>BugTest</h1>
    <example-browser></example-browser>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think repeating over a list of elements is working.

You should only repeat over model data.

What your code does, is

```dart
<template repeat="{{track in tracks}}">
  <example-track></example-track> <!-- this element is created tracks.lenght times -->
</template>
```

the content of your `tracks` list is ignored completely (beside the number of entries) because you don't refer to it in your markup. You would get the same example if you use `@observable List tracks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`

You should call `render()` in `ExampleTrack`'s `attached()` instead.

This way you get data from your `tracks` list to your created `ExampleTrack`

```dart
<template repeat="{{track in tracks}}">
  <example-track someattribute="{{track.aField}}"></example-track> 
</template>
```

If you want to trigger updates in your generated `ExampleTrack`s, change the bound model value (`tracks[0].aField = 'someNewValue';`) and let the `ExampleTrack` do something in `void someattributeChanged(old) { /* do something */ }`

You have to take care, that `tracks` and the elements inside it and their fields are observable.
Search for `[dart] observable` on SO there should be enough examples.

Comment: Thanks Günter for the quick response. In the actual app, the elements instantiated inside the repeated template have attributes that are pulled from each track instance. I'd also like to be able to re-render the tracks as needed. The problem seems to persist whether using a single instance. I've edited the question to make these points clearer.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should really reconsider your approach, it's not how Polymer works.

Comment: Spot on. Adding void attributeChanged(old) {whatever} is a *much* better way of getting what I wanted done. Thanks Günter!

Comment: Seems you got it! Have fun with Poylmer!